# Цена нефти или цена на нефть?

Tags: управление

как будет правильно: цена нефти или цена на нефть?

Или то и другое верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба выражения правильны, но "цена на нефть" используется чаще, а "цена за нефть" не используется вовсе, хотя есть выражение "цена за баррель нефти". А почему именно так? Мне кажется, что ответить на этот вопрос можно, если в различных ситуациях подобрать синонимы для слова "цена".

Если мы считаем, что цена - это условно стоимость нефти, то говорим "цена нефти".

Если считать, что они отнюдь не одинаковы и цена  устанавливается как стоимость плюс рыночная наценка, то получается "цена на нефть".

Если мы покупаем товар, то платим за него деньги (они как бы следуют за товаром), и тогда говорим о цене как о плате: цена за проезд, за образовательные услуги, за баррель нефти.

Во всех этих примерах используется В.п. с разными предлогами, но ведь есть еще Д.п. - например, цена хлебу. Здесь слово "цена" приобретает не прямой, а переносной смысл  - это степень ценности и значимости предмета.

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта применимы к любым товарам и услугам, но различаются по ситуации употребления. Когда говорят о свойствах какого-либо товара, "цена товара" выступает одним из таковых (это изделие хорошо тем-то, цена его такая-то; цена входного билета такая-то). Но с другой стороны, цена (в отличие от стоимости) является ещё и внешним условием, её устанавливают "на товар" в интересах его продажи, и она может меняться теми, от кого это зависит. Есть "цена билета", но "цены на билеты" "на"значаются людьми, и под этим подразумеваются "цены, установленные на билеты" в сложившейся экономической ситуации. В этом примере вариант "на билеты" в единственном числе почти не применяется, обычно говорят и пишут "цена билета" ("билет стоит" столько то - цена уже стала его свойством). По всей видимости, вариант "цена на" сохраняет в себе отзвук процесса установления (повышения и снижения) цены теми, кто "над этим", и он уместнее в ситуации изменения цен. Если "цены (устанавливаемые) на нефть" давно не пересматривались её продавцами, то "цена нефти", этакая константа (одно из свойств нефти данного сорта), может использоваться при планировании расходов на что-нибудь.

Answer (score 1):

ЦЕНА ***чего, кому-чему, за что и на что.*** Цена одной пары туфель - 30 рублей. Цена всему этому грош. Цена за билет в кинотеатр.

*Остался бы ты, Анисим, дома, - сказал он, - цены бы тебе не было (Чехов). ...Мужик сам знает цену хлебу (А.Н.Толстой).
На святках цена за прокат саней поднялась втрое (Гл.Успенский). По мере спроса на ее
[белки] мех цена на него возрастала... (Арсеньев)... Ваза ценой 25 рублей (ценой в 25 рублей)*.[Здесь](http://www.interword.se/Syntax/Lektionsmaterial/Rozenthal_Rektion.pdf)

Цена НА НЕФТЬ и НЕФТИ. Верны оба варианта.